# How to put three divs next to each other in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to display 3 div elements inline with each other and does not resize even if you change the size of the browser how do I go about it?

How it should look like:
[image: What it should look like]

**Code**:

```css
body {}

#wrap {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0px solid;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}

#one {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

#two {
    background: yellow;
}

#three {
    width: 40%;
    float: inherit;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
    <div id="two">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
    <div id="three">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `#two` div isn't floating... and acts as a block level element (as it should, BTW...) 
Check my answer :-)

Comment: Give fixed width to those divs and use float: left;

Comment: thank you for replying so fast, i did try that but once i change the size of the browser the 3rd div i have made, ends up going below div1 once i have alot of information in those divs its going to look weird do you perhaps have a solution for this?

Comment: @Julius check my answer. you should give ALL your divs float:left; AND a fixed with (in percents), and you'll be OK :-)

Comment: @Julius, you have width: auto; width: 40%; Instead of those you sould use something like width: 400px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4asacze/)

```css
#wrap::after {
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}

#wrap div {
    float: left;
    word-break: break-all;
}

#one {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
}

#two {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#three {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
    <div id="two">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
    <div id="three">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! thats exactly what i wanted

Comment: @Julius So marking it as the correct answer is the right thing to do :-)

Comment: Im trying too its telling me to wait 50secs

Answer (score 2):

`#two` and `#three`(inherits from parent which is none) do not have `float:left` and you should give `width` to those element. For example, here I give `width:32%` to all div elements(`#one`, `#two`, `#three`).

```css
 .fl-l
{
  float:left;
  word-break: break-all;
   width: 32%;
}

#wrap{
    width:auto;
 margin:0 auto;
  border:0px solid;
 height:200px;
  display:block;
  
}
#one {
  background:red;
}

#two {
 background:yellow;
}

#three {
   background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one" class="fl-l"> BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
    <div id="two" class="fl-l"> BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
    <div id="three" class="fl-l">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! thats exactly what i wanted

Comment: @Julius You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the width, set an absolute value to the `wrap` element.

```css
body {} 
#wrap {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0px solid;
  height: 200px;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-size: 0;
}
#wrap > div {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  }
#one {
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
}
#two {
  width: 20%;
  background: yellow;
}
#three {
  width: 40%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="one">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
  <div id="two">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
  <div id="three">BREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAKBREAK</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would collapse all of the `height`, `display`, `overflow` & `font-size` into a separate css declaration and avoid all duplication :-)

Comment: @RonenCypis Yes, so would I, given a bit of time to think about it (done now).  My main aim was to propose the inline-block solution.  I always run into trouble with floats.